# Can I format excel column after exporting using table export jquery plugin with bootstrap table

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table to display some data in my web application. https://bootstrap-table.com/ and I want to put an export feature in. The docs say to use https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin so I have added this to my imports and made the necessary code changes. Within the docs for this it says you can specify a format for the cells you are exporting by applying optional html data attributes while generating the table but how do I do this if my table is generated using bootstrap-table. I can't seem to work it out.. I basically need to the html data attribute data-tableexport-msonumberformat="0" to a set of td's generated by my bootstrap-table javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="/webjars/bootstrap-table/1.16.0/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-light">
<button id="exportExcelBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">
        Export 
    </button>
<table id="table"></table>

<script src="/webjars/bootstrap-table/1.16.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap-table/1.16.0/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#exportExcelBtn').on('click', function () {
            $('#table').tableExport({
                type: 'excel',
                fileName: "Order Summary"
            });
        });
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            url: '/getTableData',
            columns: [
                {
                    field: 'orderNo',
                    title: 'Order No',
                    sortable: true
                },
                {
                    field: 'itemNo',
                    title: 'Item No',
                    sortable: true,
                    **tableExport: {msoNumberFormat: '0'}**
                }
        })

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/himingby/tableExport.jquery.plugin/blob/master/test/index.html

could you try this below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoOnMsoNumberFormat(cell, row, col) {
var result = "";
if (row > 0 && col === 0)
  result = "\\@";
else if (row > 0 && col === 2)
  result = "0"; // #issue 327: Preserve long numbers
return result;
```

};

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#exportExcelBtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#table').tableExport({
            type: 'excel',
            fileName: "Order Summary"，
            mso:{onMsoNumberFormat: DoOnMsoNumberFormat},
        });
    });
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        url: '/getTableData',
        columns: [
            {
                field: 'orderNo',
                title: 'Order No',
                sortable: true
            },
            {
                field: 'itemNo',
                title: 'Item No',
                sortable: true
        
            }
    })

});
```